# Use of word 'afraid'

Tags: word-usage

I have used the following sentence. I am not sure whether the use of word "afraid" conveys the correct meaning.

> I am afraid it did not quite answer my question

Answer (score 1):

If you could replace the phrase, "I am afraid " with "Unfortunately," in your intended meaning, then yes, you used it correctly, as in [definition 2 here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afraid).

> **afraid** (adj): filled with concern or regret over an unwanted situation

Note that this definition of afraid is often used with some sarcasm.  For instance, if I caught one of my chemistry students cheating, and he or she offered a poor excuse, I might say

> I'm afraid you'll have to come up with a better story than that.

and I would not have any concern whatsoever about the unfortunate social situation the student was in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rephrasing the following way might help you understand it more easily:

> I'm afraid that you might freak out to learn that he's not coming tonight.

Answer (score 0):

The main sense of afraid is feeling fear, frightened, or worried when you think something bad might happen.

The phrase "I am afraid" is used to mean that I am sorry to have to say; you use it as a polite way of telling somebody something that's unpleasant, disappointing, or something you don't agree on.

You have used the phrase correctly in the second sense.